# Setting Custom File Name in Apache HttpClient

Tags: java, httpclient, apache-httpcomponents

I am using Apache HttpClient to upload a file through MultipartEntity, I need to upload the file with different filename.. Below is my code...

```
FileBody uploadFilePart = new FileBody(binaryFile);
MultipartEntity reqEntity = new MultipartEntity();
reqEntity.addPart("bin", uploadFilePart);
reqEntity.addPart("comment", comment);
httpPost.setEntity(reqEntity);

HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httpPost);
HttpEntity resEntity = response.getEntity();

System.out.println("----------------------------------------");
System.out.println(response.getStatusLine());
if (resEntity != null) {
    System.out.println("Response content length: " +
                       resEntity.getContentLength());
}
EntityUtils.consume(resEntity);
```

Help Appreciated!

Thanks,
Surez

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can set file name with the following [`FileBody`](http://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client-ga/httpmime/apidocs/org/apache/http/entity/mime/content/FileBody.html#FileBody%28java.io.File,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%29) constructor.

```
public FileBody(File file,
                String filename,
                String mimeType,
                String charset)
```

Comment: FYI that method is deprecated in more recent releases, but you can still set the name in the constructor.